# the most fast way to select/load data from mysql to memory/pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, select, fetchall

I have an application which do mysql reads intensively and usually it needs to read lots of data from mysql(e.g. ~100K rows one time); but i found it's very slow, especially when read it to pandas. here is what i tried:

option-1:  pure sql+Sequel=~**38ms**

select all the 100K rows using pure sql

```
select * FROM thetable
```

in a db workbench(Sequel) which cost about 38ms;

option-2:  `MySQLdb connector + fetchall()` = ~**1.6s**

option-3:  `MySQLdb connector + pandas.read_sql(sql, conn)` = ~**1.7s**

option-3:  `pymysql connector + pandas.read_sql(sql, conn)` = ~**4.3s**
It seems that use MySQLdb rather than pymysql can speed about 3X, but how can I achieve the performance as pure SQL does?